# LineageOS doing factory reset after each boot

Tags: twrp, boot-loop, lineageos, samsung-galaxy-note

- Phone: Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (hlte)
- LineageOS: 18.1-20230923-nightly-hlte-signed
- Gapps: Open GApps arm 11.0-micro
- Recovery: TWRP 3.7.0_9-0

The phone boots until the welcome screen. Then an error message appears, but it is shown only short, so I can't see it. It is covered immediately by a window saying „factory data reset“.
Only seconds later it boots into recovery.

LineageOS doesn't seem to be totally broken, as it reaches the welcome screen. But it always issues that message about doing a factory reset. What should I do next? Trying a different GApps package? Or did I miss something important?

E.g. LineageOS provides a recovery for hlte, as well, but I was thinking an actual TWRP should be good as well, shouldn't it?